# Django how to group by multiple fields and sum

Tags: django

I am trying to perform multiple group_by's on my table with the fields same as the serializer below (last column is money)

```
class MoneySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
money_sum = serializers.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model =  my_models.Money
    fields = ('date', 'city', 'money_sum')
```

My Query in my viewset is as follows

```
items = my_models.Money.objects.values('date', 'city').annotate(money_sum=Sum('money'))
```

But with this, I'll have a group_by done for the city column, but I'll still have duplicates for the date field. I would like to group the rows such that it groups by all the same city values and all the same date values.

edit: my model

```
class Money(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    city = models.models.CharField(max_length=200)
    money = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
```

Comment: Can you post your `Money` model? Also have you overriden the default manager?

Comment: your query should group by *distinct ('date', 'city') pair*, not just city. It's not clear what you mean by "group by all same city values and all same date values". What about two rows with the same date but a different city? Also if you customise `objects` or add a default `order` on your model, this will affect your results.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an [**`order_by`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) to force a `GROUP BY` here:

```
Money.objects.values('date', 'city').annotate(
    money_sum=Sum('money')
).order_by('date', 'city')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` of `dict`ionaries, like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'date': date(2019, 1, 1), 'city': 'Berlin', 'money_sum': 1425.00},
    {'date': date(2019, 1, 1), 'city': 'Vienna', 'money_sum': 1302.00},
    {'date': date(2019, 2, 9), 'city': 'Madrid', 'money_sum': 1789.00},
    {'date': date(2019, 6, 29), 'city': 'Vienna', 'money_sum': 2019.00}
]>
```